# How to capture all the events sent to the system on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cydia-substrate

I want to capture all the human interface devices events that are come from users' operations, such as touch inside, touch move, shake...
I know it's a good method to use MobileSubstrate to hook on the ways of the events, but I don't know where should I hook.I do not mean catch the events of only one special app, but in the whole system.
I'll be appreciated for any advice.
Thank you.

Comment: what you are trying to do here is effectively a keylogger, no?

Comment: keylogger?no, I'm trying to make an operations recorder that can record the operations and playback them.

Comment: Why even use mobile substrate?  Assert yourself just above the driver level, because that's really the only proper way this is ever going to work.